# Make sure only one record inserted in table with thousands of concurrent users

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Recently, I needed to write a stored procedure to insert only one record when the first user come and ignore for others. I think the `IF NOT EXISTS INSERT` will not work for me. Also, some people saying online that MERGE adds race condition. Any quick way to achieve this? This is my code for now.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ......)
INSERT
```

Comment: Post your sample data and expected result.

Comment: What about adding a Check constraint on count?

Answer (score 0):

You might add another table to use as the lock mechanism.

Let's say your table's name is `a`, and the name of the table which has the locked value is `check_a` :

```
create table a (name varchar(10))
create table check_a (name varchar(10))
```

Insert only one record to the lock table:

```
insert into check_a values ('lock')
go
```

Then create a stored procedure which checks if there is a value in the main table. If there is no record, we might lock the only value in the table `check_a` and insert our value into the table `a`.

```
create proc insert_if_first
as
begin
    set nocount on
    if not exists (select name from a)
    begin
        declare @name varchar(10)
        begin tran
        select @name = name from check_a with (updlock)
        if not exists (select name from a)
        begin
            insert into a values ('some value')
        end
        commit
    end
end

go
```

First selection from the table `a` to check there is no record is for using system resources as low as we can. If there is a record in the table `a`, we can skip opening transaction and skip locking the row.

Second check is to make sure that while we are waiting to obtain the lock, no one inserted a row to the table `a`.

This way, only the first user which can lock `check_a` will be able to insert a value to the table `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you mean you want users to make a stored procedure that makes sure only one user can run the procedure. Then you need to use isolation levels. There are different Isolation levels, so you need to decide which one you need.

- `READ UNCOMMITTED`
- `READ COMMITTED`
- `REPEATABLE READ`
- `SERIALIZABLE`

You can read what they do here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx